# How to remove spacing between recycler view items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I am getting space between each item in recycler view. I want to remove that, I want Game label to be connected with Upper part.

[image]

In my layout i am not using any margin or padding on top and bottom.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Game"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/team_one_IV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#004187"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/team_one_IV2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#004187"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_one_IV" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLineSecond"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"

        android:background="@drawable/line"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_one_IV"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Following is my recycler view code.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_score_board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Are you sure if you are sharing the correct layout? From my side, it looks like, we do not have the same layout as we are seeing in the screenshot. The `ivLineSecond` taking up the height at the bottom of each item and `team_one_IV` is centred. Not sure if we can reproduce your problem with this. Please update your layout with the exact code that you have and let us know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to constrain the button of the        `android:id="@+id/ivLineSecond"` 
to the button of         `android:id="@+id/team_one_IV2"`  
and make their height equal to each other as this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Game"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/team_one_IV"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#004187"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/team_one_IV2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#004187"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_one_IV" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivLineSecond"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/line"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/team_one_IV2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_one_IV"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by following ways:
From xml for `RecyclerView`:

```xml
   android:divider="@null"
   android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

And also by setting a custom divider decoration from Java/ Kotlin code:

```kotlin
   // Get reference to the RecyclerView first
   // In Kotlin
   recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, null))

   // In Java
   recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, null));
```

Also you can adjust the `padding/ margins` for the list item view to get to the desired spacing behavior.